# Are sequenceable groups self-reducible?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, combinatorial-group-theory

A non-trivial finite group $G$ of order $n$ is said to be sequenceable if its elements can be arranged in a sequence ($g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots ,g_{n}$) in such a way that the partial products ($a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots , a_{n}$), where $a_{i}=g_{1}g_{2} \dots g_{i}$ are distinct. The sequence ($g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots g_{n}$) is called a sequencing for G.

I was trying to prove that the problem of testing whether a group is sequenceable(GS) is self-reducible, or may be random self-reducible. Or can it be proven that this problem is not self-reducible.

One approach that I thought was to consider a variant of this problem PREFIX SEQUENCEABILITY (PS), where we have a given ordering of some of the prefix elements of $G$, say $P=(g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots g_{k}$), and we want to check whether there is a sequence of G which extends P. It can be easily proved that PS is self-reducible.

One way to show GS is self-reducible would be to show a reduction from PS($G,P$) to GS($G′$) . If we could show such a reduction, then, since, PS is self-reducible, so GS is also self-reducible. We want to construct the group $G′$ in such a way that G′ is sequenceable if and only if $G$ contains a sequence that extends P.

Can someone provide some ideas on how to do this construction, or give ideas on proving GS is self-reducible in some other way ?

Comment: Please remind us of what it means for a problem to be "self-reducible".

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53921/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4877830/14578, https://mathoverflow.net/q/464123/37212.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: A problem is said to be self-reducible if the search problem reduces in polynomial time to decision problem. For the GS problem, we want to show that if there is a access to a black-box or an oracle that can tell us whether a given group $G$ is sequenceable or not in polynomial time, then can we find the sequence in polynomial time?